# Numbrix Generator Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'd been trying to program a [Numbrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidato) generator with two conditions:

- Square grid 10 x 10
- Number 1 is on the bottom row of the grid and 100 on the top row

Rules of Numbrix are that every number must have a side (in the grid) in common with the following number.

I'd been trying to make an algorithm that generates a random grid that satisfies what I said and I'd been unable of doing so. My main attempt was to simply keep trying a path randomly, going back when needed, until I ended up with a path that finished with 100 on top row, but that seemed to be too inefficient.

I hoped to find here a guideline on how to build such algorithm.

I'd been trying to do so in C++, but since the main issue here is the algorithm, language shouldn't be the issue.

Here's my algorithm right now:

```
int nrow = 10;
int ncol = 10;

typedef vector< vector<int> > matrix;

bool generate_path(int x, int y, matrix &grid, int value, int maxused)
{
    if(x == 0) maxused++;
    if(maxused == ncol && value != nrow*ncol) return(false);
    grid[x][y] = value;
    if(grid[x][y] == nrow * ncol)
    {
        if(x == 0) return(true);
        grid[x][y] = 0;
        return(false);
    }
    // 0: North, 1: East, 2: South, 3: West
    bool directions[4];
    directions[0] = y+1 < ncol && grid[x][y+1] == 0;
    directions[1] = x+1 < nrow && grid[x+1][y] == 0;
    directions[2] = y > 0      && grid[x][y-1] == 0;
    directions[3] = x > 0      && grid[x-1][y] == 0;
    while(directions[0] || directions[1] || directions[2] || directions[3])
    {
        int direction = rand() % 4;
        while(!directions[direction]) direction = rand() % 4;
        switch(direction)
        {
            case 0:
                if(generate_path(x, y+1, grid, value+1, maxused)) return(true);
                directions[direction] = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                if(generate_path(x+1, y, grid, value+1, maxused)) return(true);
                directions[direction] = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                if(generate_path(x, y-1, grid, value+1, maxused)) return(true);
                directions[direction] = false;
                break;
            case 3:
                if(generate_path(x-1, y, grid, value+1, maxused)) return(true);
                directions[direction] = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    grid[x][y] = 0;
    return(false);
}

matrix generate_grid(const int &mult)
{
    matrix grid(nrow, vector<int> (ncol, 0));
    int x = nrow-1;
    int y = rand() % ncol;
    generate_path(x, y, grid, 1, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) for(int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) grid[i][j] = grid[i][j] * mult;
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: A backtracking algorithm - which you have a flavor of - is a perfectly reasonable approach to this problem. [It's a common way to implement a Sudoku solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Backtracking), which is a similar problem. What do you feel is the problem?

Comment: While it seems to work for 6x6 grids (for example) it takes **way too long** for 10x10 grids.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to backtrack sooner than what you're currently doing?

Comment: Show your existing algorithm?

Answer (score -2):

When I do Numbrix, I've noticed that the numbers are usually in random places, but there is always a bridge of numbers to get to the other number, and there are no blockages.

You could just write out a Numbrix yourself on paper instead of trying to figure it out on the computer. Or, you could look up Numbrix and write down theirs, but alter it a little to your own liking. Hope this helps!